# How to use TCP sampler in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, java, performance, groovy, jmeter

I am sending Text to server using TCP sampler , I am getting following error "Response code: 500
Response message: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"
And also I tried JSR223sampler to check the connection even server is not connected throwing same error

```
`def sock =new Socket();
sock.setSoTimeout(100000);
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress("ip",port));
if(sock.isConnected()){
    log.info('Connected');
}
else{
    log.info('server is not connected');
}
```

,
Do I need to add any configuration in System.properties file/Jmeter.bat file

find the screenshot for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your machine can connect to the specified host/port combination, you can validate this using [telnet client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_clients), once you're connected - you should be able to do this using both approaches with JMeter.

I will be using `echo.websocket.org` host and port `80` in further examples:

[image]

As you can see I can connect to that host using telnet client therefore I should be able to do the same with JMeter:

[image]

You may also find [How to Load Test TCP Protocol Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter) guide useful

If you're not able to connect the host/port combination using telnet either the host is down or it's unreachable (i.e. you're behind a network [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)), if this is the case you will need to have a [TCP Proxy](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/denial-of-service-network-tcp-proxy-understanding.html))